# Weird error in subclass with file name

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

my code:

```
public class ArmyDivison extends DragonArmy {

  public ArmyDivison(String name) {
    super(name);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        army.add(new Dragon(i,j,true));
        army.add(new Dragon(i,j,false));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error message:

```
ArmyDivision.java:1: error: class ArmyDivison is public, should be declared in a file named ArmyDivison.java
public class ArmyDivison extends DragonArmy {
       ^
1 error
```

The file name is `ArmyDivison.java`, by the way for anyone wondering, `DragonArmy` and its class file exist and are in the same folder.

Comment: Your .java file name and your class name are different.

Comment: How is it weird if it clearly states the issue: "class ArmyDivison is public, should be declared in a file named ArmyDivison.java"?

Comment: Note the missing `i` in your class name.

Answer (score 2):

The file name is Army**Division**, but your class name is Army**Divison**. Fix the class name typo and it should be fine. The file name and public class names need to match in Java:

```
ArmyDivision.java:1: error: class ArmyDivison is public,
```

Answer (score 2):

**Credit to [@Eran's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221571/eran) comment. If he wants to make an answer for himself I will delete mine.**

> ArmyDivision.java:1: error: class ArmyDivison is public, should be declared in a file named ArmyDivison.java
>   public class ArmyDivison extends DragonArmy {

It's a typo

- `ArmyDivision` : your file name
- `ArmyDivison` : your class name (note the missing "i")

PS: You've made the same typo when creating this question it seems, because your following statement:

> The file name is ArmyDivison.java, by the way for anyone wondering

conflicts with the error. :)